# xfce4/gtk-3.0 - Changing text color for the panel DateTime widget?

Tags: colors, configuration, widget, gtk3, xfce

I'm using `xfce4` built on top of `gtk-3.0`. Here is the system info ...

`System:    Host: XXXXXXXX.XXX Kernel: 4.4.0-81-generic x86_64 (64 bit) Desktop: Xfce 4.11.8 Distro: Linux Mint 17 Qiana`

I am trying to change the text color of the `DateTime` widget on the panel, but none of the things I have tried is working. I have a dark panel background, so I want white text for the date and time info within this widget.

I'm using the `oxygen-gtk` theme, so I inserted this code in `/usr/share/themes/oxygen-gtk/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` and restarted. But I'm still getting black clock text ...

```
ClockBox {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

I also tried installing this same configuration info in the corresponding gtk config files for various other themes and tried each of these themes, making a point to comment out their existing `ClockBox` configuration, if it exists. After restarting, I am still getting black date-time text for each and every one of these themes.

In addition, for any of those themes which already had a `ClockBox` configuration, I just changed the existing config info to be the same as the default, except for it to contain `color: #ffffff;`. After restarting, I still get black date-time text.

Can anyone point me to instructions for changing the text color of the `xfce4` `DateTime` widget?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could it be that the `ClockBox` configuration does not control the `DateTime` widget? If so, where can I find the info for how to configure the `DateTime` widget?

Comment: PS: I found the `orage clock`, which does allow the setting of text color (after `apt-get install orage`, it is available as another `xfce4` panel widget). However, I'm still wondering if there is a way to control the text color of the `DateTime` widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using an old development release (4.11) instead of the current stable (4.12)?

Anyway, both versions are Gtk2-based, but this version of panel might support Gtk3 plugins, which is not the case for datetime until its 0.7.0 release.

Unfortunately, there's no class available that we could use a selector:
[image: GtkInspector on datetime plugin]

You have the following options:

- Open a [request](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/buglist.cgi?component=General&list_id=36931&product=Xfce4-datetime-plugin&resolution=---) to add a css class to allow custom styling.
- Investigate the use of [Text Attribute Markup](https://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/PangoMarkupFormat.html). It works well for clock plugin, where I can set the font & color, but not for datetime. I don't know if it's regression of 0.7.0.
- Update the [patch which provides GUI settings](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=9487) to set the labels colors.
- Use clock plugin with the custom format.

Comment: 4.11 is the release that comes with my linux repo. I could push to a higher release, but that means other repo changes, so that will have to wait. Anyway, I'll check as soon as I am able about 4.12 or later.

Comment: Anyway, I accept these 4 suggestions collectively as a very good answer.